# Best Time to Save UserSettings

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a .Net application that uses their user settings.  What is the best time to save these settings?

To be clear, I'm calling this function to save the:

```
Storage.Properties.Settings.Default.Save()
```

First, I though to save them on every change, but that's slow, and don't seem to be necessary.  The documentation suggest that they only need to be saved when the application is closing, in in their example, when a form is closing.

But, what if there are two instances of the application running?  It seems that if I wait until Application_Exit event, the settings won't persist between the instances.  The new instance of the application would read the old user settings, causing an error.

So, what's the best practice for this?

Comment: Is this a Visual studio extension? Or a win app?

Comment: This is a win app.  C#, .Net 4, WPF 4.  If I mis-tagged question, sorry, just let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is application specific, so there is no best practice.  Some apps don't even allow multiple instances, for example.

But most apps tend to do one of these things:

- They don't change settings often, so save an entire set of changes at once (e.g. when applying changes in a configuration dialog).
- They change often, in the background, so set some sort of timer event to save at a particular interval.
- They change often, but explicitly, so have some sort of "save changes" button for the user to click.

The problem with saving on exit is that your changes may be lost when you have a bug that causes an unhandled exception.  If your app is supposed to run in the background, this might happen more often than you think, especially while it is still in development/testing.

I went with a "save on exit" strategy with a toy system-tray style app I wrote several years back, and regretted it.  Explicit saves and/or interval saves would have been a much better option.

Comment: I agree.  My app needs to support multiple instances.  I generally save when forms close.  With, WPF, and binding, I save user settings whenever a user interacts with the interface.  But, the one case that is causing me worry, is I have an XML database with bookmarks.  The bookmarks each have a unique ID.  So, I use the user settings to save the last unique ID.  So, if I save every time I change the user ID, it's slow to import large sets.  If I save when application exits, there's could be problems with multiple instances.  Save after the import makes code still has problems.

Comment: @Michael: It sounds like you should adopt multiple strategies: always save instantly on the GUI, and support a "batch import" mode that saves a whole group of changes in one go, rather than once-per-item.

Comment: nice answer. i would like to add my two cents to it.
personally, i would have NOT save the changes unless the user specificly clicks the "Save changes" button, BUT, i would keep the setting in memory while the application runs.
so, even if multiple instances are running, the main configuration will not change unless the user specificly asks for it,
but it can be temporary changed so the user could work with diffrent settings.

Comment: @Michael: Also, if you really have a good reason to support multiple instances sharing the data, then you should strongly consider using a more robust database as your back-end.  Sqlite might be a good option.

Comment: @Dementic: Good thought.  I'm not going to edit the answer in this case, since my point boils down to "your app is a unique snowflake, and there is no one-size-fits-all solution" ;)

Comment: My app has a class that creates a new document, and calls save when that document is created.  When creating lots of documents quickly, I'm just going to pass an optional parameter to that function that tells it to delay the write to disk.  Problem solved, and though it's not 100% correct, I would be very surprised if I ever see an error because of this.  I don't think the same user will run the same feature on two different versions of this application at the same time.  Wouldn't make any sense.  Thanks for your advice and feedback.

Comment: @Merlyn: I use sqlite for other projects, but I've never used for .Net.  And, there's no good reason for a user to do this; I'm just thinking about worst cases.

Comment: @Michael: "there's no good reason for a user to do this".  If so, then you could protect yourself from bugs by forcing a single instance.  We did this on an app at the previous company I worked for, and it ended up being a good choice.  Here's an example of how - http://www.ai.uga.edu/mc/SingleInstance.html, though I suggest just popping up the existing instance, rather than popping up a dialog.